# How does one make the home halal when living with a Christian guardian?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, conversion, family

Wa salaamaleykum

I am I newly converted Muslim. My family is specifically Catholic.  How can I make my living area halal? Specifically, there are many photos and figurines, depicting people & animals, on display; however, there are no icons (crosses, crucifixes, idols, or even bibles present).

Also are featureless little statues haram? (those with defined no eyes, nose, mouth) Will these void my prayers?

My father is tolerant, but not overly accepting of my faith.  So blatant redecorating is not an option.  I take care of him and moving out is not a feasible option. I have to be respectful to my father, but also need to live as Allah, the most merciful, commands. I feel like it is not good right now.

Thank you! May Allah bless you all for your sadaqah tul jaareah. Amin

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you seem to emphasize on the topic of guardianship, would you mind elaborating in case it is as important as I deduced from your post title?. .. Note that a non-Muslim can't be guardian for a Muslim.

Comment: s.a. He is my 100% disabled father, stressed to detail my situation better. Im taking care of him, until my fiance & I can afford relocation, marriage, home etc. It's my father's home that I live. Your reply brings up a nother question, as what basis is my biological father unable to continue to be my guardian, I am not yet married & he's paying most of my expenses? What are the repercussions as out of my control for several months?  (moving as clarified is not immediately possible). he is not oppressing my faith. I thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Prayer is not rendered void by images, although it is *makruh* to pray in a place where the image will be in the direction of the qiblah in front of you, or on your sides or behind you etc. You may see if you are allowed to clear-out any images from your own room, you can offer prayers in a masjid or even outside, and in the long-run you may consider convincing your father or even moving out.

Some schools allow for temporarily staying in a place with images, based on e.g. the agreement that Umar ibn Khatab made with the Christians that they will host the Muslims and allow them to stay overnight in their churches.

[Arabic Ref: p 124-127](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk12#page/n124/mode/2up)

Comment: thank you.  I think I will remain with praying outside when possible.  inşallah I will move sooner than later. Im unable to read arabic, but take classes, so I am unsure what you referenced to not have to ask for a translation, as it's too small to detect with my translate app. My room itself is free of graven images but really no way to avoid them in the house overall.  I heard photo/statues were likened to being magnets for the şeytan! my deceased mother's trinkets& photos of family in display are everywhere in the other rooms except direction I face during prayer, so Im virtually surrounded